# XSS, why is alert(XSS) used to find/demonstrate xss vulnerabilities?

Tags: xss

I was wondering why alert() is quite often used to demonstrate XSS vulnerabilities. If I am not mistaken XSS means that the attacker should be able to establish two-way communication between infected client and attacker's server. It is just that this is a quite visual way to demonstrate that the attack is possible (as it uses the same characters as the actual payload would have) or is there something more?  I tried to look it up online but found nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it. it's demonstrated with an alert because when the alert is shown, it means the attacker was able to insert javascript code into your page and that code was executed as if you had put it there yourself. ... so from the perspective of the client (visitor) this code is coming from you, and they don't know anything about the attacker - which is what the attacker wants.

Answer (score 1):

It's just like a "hello world" program but from the XSS world. It's easy to check, minimalistic, checking that you can at least execute some javascript function (alert). While you're looking for an XSS, the payload itself is not as important as the "can I actually inject some javascript here?" question.

Basically, it's a 2 steps approach.

1. Find a vulnerable parameter. (using alert or any other simple function)
2. Now let's have some fun with it.

> If I am not mistaken XSS means that the attacker should be able to establish two-way communication between infected client and attacker's server.

Not always. Sometimes, 1-way communication is enough:

1. Just send data to your server, no response required. It's very useful for the stored XSS case (when let's say you can put random javascript code into a comment visible to other users)
2. You can inject some HTML asking the user to open another website and do whatever you want. (XSS + social engineering)

To summarise: alert is a simple function sufficient to check if you can inject javascript, like "hello world" to check that your setup is working. If you're successful -> it's time to make it more complicated.

Edit: in a real attack, people usually check more options, because the "alert" keyword is blocked by most security filters. It doesn't mean that the XSS is not there ;) But "alert" is a very convenient example for tutorials, so you'll see it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering why alert() is quite often used to demonstrate XSS vulnerabilities.

Simply because the `alert()` method is the best option to show people that you are able to insert JS code into the page.

> If I am not mistaken XSS means that the attacker should be able to establish two-way communication between infected client and attacker's server.

Kinda. XSS just means that the attacker is able to inject malicious JS into the page.

> It is just that this is a quite visual way to demonstrate that the attack is possible (as it uses the same characters as the actual payload would have) or is there something more?

It's just the visual way.
However JS can be sandboxed in iframes etc. so the `alert('XSS')` is not the best method to show that you are able to inject malicious code.
The best way is to use some information from the page itself. For example

```
alert(`XSS attack on ${window.location.host}'s page: "${document.title}"`)
```

is a lot better way to demonstrate. It shows that you can have access to window properties (redirect) and document (modify) as well.

On this page it would display:

> XSS attack on stackoverflow.com's page: "XSS, why is alert(XSS) used to find/demonstrate xss vulnerabilities? - Stack Overflow"